# Will GLSurfaceView render a bitmap faster than SurfaceView?

Tags: android, opengl-es, bitmap

I'm rendering video from some external source as a series of bitmaps to a `SurfaceView`. Sometimes the rendering is not fast enough.

I'm thinking of replacing SurfaceView with GLSurfaceView for bitmap rendering but then, since these are bitmaps and nothing like Open GL vectors  I don't think the rendering will become faster.

Shall I expect it to become faster? The change will require me brushing up some OpenGL knowledge so I thought I'd better ask here first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is your surfaceview hardware accelerated (I think pre 3.0 they are not)? If so, then it probably won't be too different. If it's not hardware accelerated it will probably make a huge difference.

If you do use OpenGL, try the DrawTexfOES function, I believe that's the fastest way to render textured quads according to Google IO presentation.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know how to determine if it's hardware accelerated (preferably at runtime) ?

Comment: @Alex see [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html). Acceleration started with Honeycomb.

Comment: There are pre-3.0 devices with GPU and there are those without GPU, do you know if I can detect that? I think OpenGL on the non-GPU devices will show even worse results than simple drawing?

Comment: @Alex see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9148751/detecting-good-gpu-on-android). Seems like there's no way. In addition to Nicol's answer, I could imagine performing a micro benchmark on the initial app start and then decide heuristically what to use.

Comment: SurfaceViews are always hardware accelerated if you use OpenGL. This has been the case since 1.0. However, if you use a Canvas to draw onto a SurfaceView it won't be hardware accelerated (the version of Android does not matter.)

Comment: @StefanHanke Hardware acceleration existed before Honeycomb if you used OpenGL directly.

Comment: @RomainGuy Yes, that statement of mine is nonsense; quite confusing though. Canvas-drawing on a SurfaceView is _not_ accelerated? "SurfaceViews are always hardware accelerated if you use OpenGL" You mean the `GLSurfaceView`? I hope I sound not _too_ naive...

Comment: GLSurfaceView is just a utility class on top of SurfaceView. You can use OpenGL with SurfaceView.